# Microsoft Office 2013 Save to SharePoint library, browse all libraries

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-library

I would like to save my file directly from office applications(word/excel).

[image]

If I go to **Save as>SharePoint>** it shows only the previous opened libraries. If I would like save this to a new library, how do I browse all the available libraries from here ? (I can copy the library path manually and access, but that is not the right approach for business users)

If i click on Browse, it will open the last used library and there is no way I can browse through the available libraries ?

P.S: **SharePoint 2013** is used here with **Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013**

Answer (score 0):

Train/instruct your business users to map (add) your SharePoint site as a network location to their "This PC". They can then navigate to the location/library (on SharePoint) they want to save to via the "Browse" icon like any other folder.